# Array of formulas

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make an objective c array in xcode with formulas like this..

- x+5
- x-5
- x/5
- x*5

So I can load a formula with arrayName[i] and give the value of x and get the answer. Is there a way to do this, if so how?

Comment: You could store an array of function pointers that take a value (`x`) and return the result.

Comment: So you can do it, but could you give an example of how?

Comment: It really depends on how general you want to make it.  You could handle what you listed with a few lines of code.  If you need to support more complex arrangements including, e.g., operator precedence, it would take a bit more.  So, you may want to expand on your objective a little bit if you want meaningful suggestions.

Comment: That sounds like a very bad way of making a function!

Comment: I'm not an objective-C guy, but from what I understand, function pointers are called `selectors` in objective-C.  I will leave it to a more capable individual to give a proper example. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this with an array of blocks. Each block would receive a parameter `x` and return a value, calculating one function of yours. Then, you can select any position of the array and execute it.

It will be something like this:

```
typedef CGFloat (^MyFunction)(CGFloat);  //using a typedef to ease the heavy syntax of the blocks

MyFunction function1 = ^CGFloat(CGFloat x){
    return x + 5;
};

MyFunction function2  = ^CGFloat(CGFloat x){
    return x - 5;
};

MyFunction function3  = ^CGFloat(CGFloat x){
    return x / 5;
};

MyFunction function4  = ^CGFloat(CGFloat x){
    return x * 5;
};

NSArray *functions = @[function1, function2, function3, function4];
```

Now you can access any position of the array, and execute the chosen block, like this:

```
MyFunction myFunction = functions[3];
CGFloat test = myFunction(5); //test will hold 25, because the selected block is 'x * 5'
```

You can obviously change the `3` for any index of the array. And of course, you can declare any other functions like the ones above and add them in your array.

I have tested and it works well. Hope it helped.

Comment: +1 One question: Any reason you chose to return `NSNumber*` rather than `CGFloat` here? Returning the same type as it takes would make it easier to chain these functions (which seems a natural thing to do for the kinds of problems the OP seems to be describing).

Comment: Nope, no concrete reason at all, just preference. I often prefer to work with NSNumbers because the flexibility of conversions, and of course, been a objective-C object, so we can store in arrays, dicts, etc. But I think you are right, to this kind of question, returning another CGFloat may be better (I edited the answer).

Comment: And is there any advantage of `CGFloat` over `float`?

Comment: `CGFloat` is just a typedef, you can command-click in xcode to see by yourself. The compiler checks the processor is 64 bits, defining the `CGFloat` as a `double`, or 32 bits, defining as a `float`. I always prefer to use cocoa types, to follow the conventions, but you can explicit use `float` or `double` if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Not to detract from Lucas's answer, but it's worth pointing out how powerful this can really be. It's difficult to get all the power of functional programming this way (particularly since the syntax starts to get in the way), but you can get many of the pieces. For example, since these blocks are created at runtime, you can create new functions on the fly. For example, you can have a function that returns a custom function:

```
typedef CGFloat (^MyFunction)(CGFloat);

MyFunction addXFunction(CGFloat toAdd) {
  return ^CGFloat(CGFloat x) {
    return x + toAdd;
  };
}

MyFunction addFive = addXFunction(5);
CGFloat fifteen = addFive(10);
```

And of course you can even do things like `map` and `reduce`, though the syntax is not quite as simple as in a true functional language:

```
NSArray * number_map(MyFunction f, NSArray *numbers) {
  NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];
  for (NSNumber *number in numbers) {
    [result addObject:@(f([number floatValue]))];
  }
  return result;
}

NSArray *numbers = @[@(1), @(2), @(3), @(4), @(5)];
MyFunction addFive = addXFunction(5);
NSArray *numbersPlusFive = number_map(addFive, numbers));
```

(I continue to be amazed that `NSArray` has no `-map` method built-in. If this bothers you, dupe [rdar://14807617](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5364414152704000).)